# How to build that in the pgfgantt environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt, charts

I am using the following code but I want to incorporate some dashes as in the picture.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,fleqn]{article} 
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
{\sffamily
\begin{ganttchart}[%
  inline, 
  y unit title=1.1cm,
  canvas/.style={draw=none},
  title/.style={draw=none},
  bar inline label anchor=west,
  bar inline label node/.append style={anchor=west, text=white},
  bar/.append style={fill=cyan!90!black,}, 
  bar height=.8,]{0}{18}
  \ganttbar[inline=false]{M1}{0}{3}
  \ganttbar{J1}{0}{3}
  \ganttbar{J2}{3}{4}
  \ganttbar{}{5}{18}\\
  \ganttbar[inline=false]{M2}{0}{5}
  \ganttbar{J2}{5}{8}
  \ganttbar{J1}{8}{12}
  \ganttbar{}{12}{18}\\
  \gantttitlelist{0,...,18}{1}
\end{ganttchart}
}
\caption{To demonstrate Flow shop Scheduling}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to rebuild my Gantt chart to get this look

?[image: is that possible]

I just want to have a line with t and dashes.  The rest should be similar to the output of the code above.

Comment: What was your last code, you posted?  It'll be much easier for us, if you gave the link yourself.

Comment: @jan the last code is there ?

Comment: I interpreted the term "the last code I posted" to be another question, you placed on TeX.SE.  At least to me your term is ambiguous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a possibility, though it's a bit of a hack.

First, add a `tikzpicture` environment around the `pgfgantt` environment. This is used to be able to draw some additional stuff.

In the `\gantttitlelist`, add `[title label node/.append style={alias=n\x,opacity=0}]`. `\x` is the number, so the node with number 1 will be given the alias `n1`, and so on. With zero opacity the numbers are invisible.

I think the nodes in the title list are placed equidistant, but because they have different widths, it isn't accurate to use their corners as references. So what I do is to calculate the horizontal distance between the centers of two of the nodes (`n0` and `n1`), and then draw the tick this distance to the left of the `north` anchor of the nodes. This appears to be accurate.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,fleqn]{article} 
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ganttchart}[%
   inline, 
   y unit title=1.1cm,
   canvas/.style={draw=none},
   title/.style={draw=none},
   bar inline label anchor=west,
   bar inline label node/.append style={anchor=west, text=white},
   bar/.append style={fill=cyan!90!black,}, 
   bar height=.8,]{0}{18}
\ganttbar[inline=false]{M1}{0}{3}
\ganttbar{J1}{0}{3}
\ganttbar{J2}{3}{4}
\ganttbar{}{5}{18}\\
\ganttbar[inline=false]{M2}{0}{5}
\ganttbar{J2}{5}{8}
\ganttbar{J1}{8}{12}
\ganttbar{}{12}{18}\\
\gantttitlelist[title label node/.append style={alias=n\x,opacity=0}]{0,...,18}{1}
\end{ganttchart}
\draw [-latex] (n0.north west) -- ([xshift=7pt]n18.north east) node[right] {$t$};
\foreach \N in {0,...,18} {
  \draw
   let
   \p1=(n0.center), \p2=(n1.center),\n1={(\x2-\x1)/2}
   in
  (n\N.north) +(-\n1,2pt) -- +(-\n1,-2pt) node[below,font=\small]{\N};
}

% draw tick for 19
\draw
   let
   \p1=(n0.center), \p2=(n1.center),\n1={(\x2-\x1)/2}
   in
  (n18.north) +(\n1,2pt) -- +(\n1,-2pt) node[below,font=\small]{19};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{To demonstrate Flow shop Scheduling}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it doesent work with \draw latex....

Comment: @MiloLi What doesn't work with what, and how does it not work? You need to be more precise.

Comment: it works, but with this solution i have the problem that the dash between 12 and 13 on M1 is wrong. The dash must be exactly over 12! Do you know what i mean ?

Comment: and the numbers on the axis look weird. It seems that they dont have the right distance. Some space is bigger some is shorter...

Comment: @MiloLi Yes, that is a problem that I didn't notice when I first posted the answer, but I did mention it in an edit (read the paragraph starting with "Note that ..."). I didn't find a good workaround yesterday, but I can try again.

Comment: OH Sorry im such a fool i did not read the whole Text.... The thing is that i dont understand the other solution that svend posted... But thanks for that reminder! It would be awesome if you could try again, i would be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: @MiloLi I thought of a way around that problem, I think it is better now.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T. but why is the dash thick now ? can i change that somewhere, and thank you very much!

Comment: @MiloLi If you're referring to the screenshot, that's just a viewer issue. If you look at the PDF, and especially if you zoom in a bit, you will see that all the ticks have the same width.

Comment: sorry next time i try it first before i say something=) thank you very much, i hope i understand it, because i have another gantt-chart! Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 3):

After finally understanding whet the OP wants, here is a possible solution, using the [`pst-plot`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-plot) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry} % avoid `overfull \hbox' warning
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\psset{
  xunit = 0.6,
  dimen = m
}

\def\Gantt(#1,#2)[#3]#4{%
  \psframe[fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = cyan]%
    (!#1 #2 0.8 sub)(!#1 #3 add #2 0.1 sub)
  \uput[0](!#1 #2 0.45 sub){\textcolor{white}{$\mathrm{#4}$}}}

% marco syntax:
% \Gantt(<t-start>,<stack number, vertical>){<t-lengte>}[<label>]


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.9,-0.52)(19.78,2.5) % boundry found manually
  \psline(0,0)(0,2.5)
  \psaxes[yAxis = false]{->}(0,0)(19.35,0)[$t$,0][,90]
  \multido{\r = 0.55+1, \i = 1+1}{2}{\rput(-0.55,\r){$\mathrm{M\i}$}}
  \Gantt(0,1)[5]{}
  \Gantt(5,1)[3]{J2}
  \Gantt(8,1)[4]{J1}
  \Gantt(12,1)[7]{}
  \Gantt(0,2)[3]{J1}
  \Gantt(3,2)[2]{J2}
  \Gantt(5,2)[14]{}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: thank you  but how can i insert more numbers and m1 m2 and j1 j2, like torbon posted.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. thank you man, but how can i put the numbers on the left, 5 must be under the dash next to J2

Comment: @MiloLi See updated answer.

Comment: but 5 is not under the dash next to j2 ? how could i change that and thanks for your quick answer..

Comment: I don't understand your question; in the screenshot of the produced output from my code, `5` is indeed under `J2` in the bottom line.

Comment: i mean the dash next to J2 @Svend Tveskæg

Comment: @MiloLi Sorry, but I still don't get it.

Comment: @ Svend Tveskæg, okay wait. I mean the 0 must start under the line  next to M1.... the numbers should all be centered more on the left. and number 5 must be under the  dash next to J2 on M1. Now you get me ?

Comment: @MiloLi See updated answer.

Comment: @MiloLi Why on earth did you ask a question to me under Svend's answer? I didn't see your comment until now, and that was just by accident.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T. sorry i was writing the wrong, thank you for your quick answer!!!

Comment: @MiloLi And when you have a space after the `@` I'm not notified. When you start writing `@Torbj...` you should see a small box with my username pop up. You can then hit the Tab-key on the keyboard to auto-complete it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. ohhh thank you very much ;) now im gettin more and more into the community!